# Connection to report server could not be made from BI VS 2005 but the report server is browseable

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, business-intelligence

I have IIS6 configured such that browsing to http://localhost:8082/Reports gets me the reporting services default home page, which is all as expected. However, when I try to publish a report via Microsoft Business Intelligence Visual Studio 2005 I get the following error: A connection could not be made to the report server  http://localhost:8082/Reports The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.

I have windows authentication turned on for report server. Does that have anything to do with not being able to publish projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot upvote, but guy is correct.  Go into Project->Properties and change TargetServerURL to "http://localhost:8082/ReportsServer".  This should alleviate your problems.

If you need to deploy to a named instance remember that your URL will be "http://servername/ReportServer$instancename".

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to publish you report to:

http://localhost:8082/ReportsServer

"/ReportsServer" is the webservice for Reporting Services.  "/Reports" is the front end.

Answer (score -3):

Step 1 : Just log in to the corresponding server

step 2 : Do the settings in internet explorer[IE] browser, Tools => Internet Options => Select connections tab => Click on  LAN settings => Just check the check box use a proxy server

Step 3 : Issue will get fixed

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which has already been answered.